# create a json file on fly and append log contents in python

Tags: python

Hi all I have a log file test.log on below format

```
{"asctime": "2021-09-07 18:58:37,645", "name": "Frontend_Tableau", "levelname": "DEBUG", "message": "Extracted Dashboard details from tableau", "type": "dashboard", "Name": "Overview"}
{"asctime": "2021-09-07 18:58:38,645", "name": "Frontend_Tableau", "levelname": "DEBUG", "message": "Extracted Dashboard details from tableau", "type": "dashboard", "Name": "Overview"}
```

I want create a json file out of this .log on fly if file does not exist on below format

```
[
  {
   "asctime": "2021-09-07 18:58:37,645",
   "name": "Frontend_Tableau", 
   "levelname": "DEBUG",
   "message": "Extracted Dashboard details from tableau",
   "type": "dashboard",
   "Name": "Overview"
  },
  {
  "asctime": "2021-09-07 18:58:38,645",
  "name": "Frontend_Tableau",
  "levelname": "DEBUG",
  "message": "Extracted Dashboard details from tableau",
  "type": "dashboard",
  "Name": "Overview"
  }
]
```

I have tried below code

```
with open(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..','logs','test_log.log'))) as logging_file:
   with open(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(log_file_path,"test_log.json")), "w") as f2:
       for line in logging_file:
           line = line.lstrip('\x00')
           f2.write(json.dumps(json.loads(line)))
```

but it does not give the output as I mentioned above. How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like:

```py
import os.path
import json

# check if file already there 
if not os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(log_file_path,"test_log.json")):
    # open log file 
    with open(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..','logs','test_log.log')),'r') as logging_file:
        # read lines of log file 
        lines = logging_file.readlines()
        # parse every line and save it to an array 
        jsonArr = [json.loads(line) for line in lines]  
        # save the new Array as a file 
        with open(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(log_file_path,"test_log.json"), 'w') as file:
            json.dump(jsonArr, file)
else:
    print("file already there")
```

Assuming that there are no empty lines in the log file, and that the path is correct.

Comment: lines variable is returning me a empty list